# Removing multiple lines in close proximity in QGIS

Tags: qgis, proximity, duplicates

I tried a suggestion to create buffer for each line (say a 10mtr buffer)
Combine all the buffers of all lines using dissolve
Try to get centerline of the combined polygon (this is where i failed... as the combined geometry was complex to get centerline)...

**Original question:**
I have a set of lines which are in close proximity to each other. I would like to retain only one line (or create a new single line) & remove all the other lines.

Rule to remove unwanted lines can be anything. At the end I would like to see only one line in the group.

For Grouping I want to consider all lines within 20 Mtrs of each other

### Original Data

### [image: original Data]

### Expected Result
[image: Expected Result]

Comment: Hi SIr, I Hope this answer will be beneficial for you:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233957/getting-centroids-for-multiple-lines

You should make something like "Centroid line" which will act as an average route between all considered on your image.

Comment: I had a similar problem that I was able to solve with this solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/418644/88814

Answer (score 3):

Your statement "...I want to consider all lines within 20 Mtrs of each other" means this is difficult to resolve. Imagine you have a bunch of parallel lines, the outer most lines are 30m apart, the inner lines are either within 20m distance of the outer lines or not at all, so which takes precedence?

Here are some Q&As on this site (there might be more you just need to search) that discuss the averaging of lines:

[Averaging polylines from a number of lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279369/averaging-polylines-from-a-number-of-lines)

[Merging average geometry of overlapping lines with differing nodes using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409329/merging-average-geometry-of-overlapping-lines-with-differing-nodes-using-qgis)

[How can I create an average/center line in from multiples lines?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179714/how-can-i-create-an-average-center-line-in-from-multiples-lines)

[Deleting overlapping lines using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255014/deleting-overlapping-lines-using-arcgis-desktop)